# Given the X numpy array, return True if any of its elements is zero

Tags: python, numpy

X is given as below:

```
X = np.array([-1, 2, 0, -4, 5, 6, 0, 0, -9, 10])
```

My answer is: `any(X==0)`.
But the standard answer is `X.any()`, and it returns `True`, which confuses me.

For me, `X.any()` is looking for if there is any `True` or `1` in the array. In this case, since there is no `1` in the given X array, it should have returned `False`. What did I get wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "`X.any()` is looking for if there is any `True` or `1` in the array" - please RTM: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html

Comment: Python and numpy see "truthy" values as true. "Truthy" means among other things all int values except 0.

Comment: What you want is `(X==0).any()`

Comment: @ForceBru I read this before, but I misunderstood what truthy value is. By the way, can you kindly explain what RTM is? I googled it but didn't find a likey definition. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelButscher Your answer is enlightening! Thanks!

Comment: @ericzheng0404, RTM stands for "Read The Manual". Doing so often helps get the definitions straight: like what a "truthy" value is or what `X.any` actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X.any()` is an incorrect answer, it would fail on `X = np.array([0])` for instance (incorrectly returning `False`).

A correct answer would be: `~X.all()`. According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), **ANY element is 0** is equivalent to **NOT (ALL elements are (NOT 0))**.

How does it work?

Numpy is doing a implicit conversion to boolean:

```
X = np.array([-1, 2, 0, -4, 5, 6, 0, 0, -9, 10])
# array([-1, 2, 0, -4, 5, 6, 0, 0, -9, 10])

# convert to boolean
# 0 is False, all other numbers are True
X.astype(bool)
# array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, True])

# are all values truthy (not 0 in this case)?
X.astype(bool).all()
# False

# get the boolean NOT
~X.astype(bool).all()
# True
```

Comment: I think your answer is a better one. By the way, does my answer ```any(X==0)``` make sense? I didn't see similar syntax used in manual examples, but it worked in this case. So, I'm wondering is it also a valid answer?

Comment: It works but this is pure python while `(X==0).any()` is vectorized. I would probably use `(X==0).any()` in a project as it is much more explicit than `~X.all()`